# What are the units for Primefaces' spacer?

Tags: primefaces

The Primefaces spacer has `width` and `height` attributes, but the Primefaces user's guide does not say what units they take. The example in the user's guide uses just numbers without a unit. It does not seem to make a difference if I add `em` or `px` as unit.

What unit is implied for `<prime:spacer width="10">`?

Comment: What does the **generated html client-side** tell you? What does the source of the component tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just renders an `img` tag with the `width` and `height` attributes set to specified values, so HTML rules for those attributes apply. In short, it's in pixels.

And to be more precise:

> **height** The intrinsic height of the image in pixels. In HTML 4, the
> height could be defined pixels or as a percentage. In HTML5, however,
> the value must be in pixels.
>
> **width** The intrinsic width of the image in pixels. In HTML 4, either a
> percentage or pixels were acceptable values. In HTML5, however, only
> pixels are acceptable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img